# Entity Framework: write-only big text column

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework. Consider the following entity class:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string BigTextColumn { get; set; }
}
```

In the backing SQL Server database I have `Foo` table with these columns: `Id, Name, BigTextColumn`.

Now I need to set `BigTextColumn` from my code. I never need to read it from database, but I need to set it on insert and update.

What are possible solutions?

Comment: You don't want to be able to access the property or you don't want EF to be able to read it (while being able to write it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use the `[NotMapped]` attribute as that makes more work for you to insert that data.

I know this technique works to make a property read-only, so I'd imagine it could be used to make it write-only. However, since you don't want to load it, you'll have to add `.Select` statements to your queries, otherwise it will pull that data in. Not necessarily the cleanest solution, but it will give you what you want without having to bend over backwards to insert and update that column.

What you'll want to do is make the `get;` on the property `protected internal` instead of the default of `public`. That way, EF will not freak out over not having access to the property, and you'll never have read access to the property outside of the data access layer of your project.

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BigTextColumn { protected internal get; set; }
}
```

Then in your queries do something like the following:

```
context.Foos.FirstOrDefault().Select(f => new Foo {
    Id = f.Id,
    Name = f.Name
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the get; property from the bigtext column that will make it write only. And then you can set its value from code. Im not sure that using the not mapped attribute will be of any help as ef will not think tact as if its not a column in your table and you won't be able to write to it.

Comment: Entity Framework will throw an exception when encountering a mapped property without both a getter and setter that it can access. See my answer on how to make that possible.